# Calculate Average of Previous Loop - Java

Tags: java, loops, random, average

So, I am working on this code for my AP Computer Science class, and I ran into a problem.

First, here is my code:

```
//loop counters
int counterOne = 0;
int counterElse = 0;
int loop = 1;
int iNum = 1000;

//create file
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("newFile.txt"));

for (int counter = 1; counter <= iNum; counter++)
    {
        while (loop >= 1)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int iRand = rand.nextInt(5)+1;

            if (iRand != 1)
            {
                counterElse++;
                loop++;
            }//end of if of if-else
            else
            {
                counterOne++;
                loop = 0;
            }//end of else of if-else

        }//end of while loop

        int tries = counterElse+counterOne;
        //int average = (tries + prevTriesSum) / counter
        System.out.println("It took " + tries + " try/tries to win!");
        //outFile.println("It tool an average of " + average + " tries to win.");

    }//end of for loop
```

How do I calculate the average of the trials? As you can see from the end of my code, I commented out a line that I would want to calculate the average. This is because I don't know how to calculate prevTriesSum, which represents the sum of all of the other trials. Here is an example: Assume the loop runs six times, and with the first run, it takes 3 tries, 5 on the second run, 7 on the third, 11 on the fourth, 2 on the fifth, and 4 on the sixth (the most recent one. now tries = 4).

I would want prevTriesSum to equal 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 2 + 4.

How do I get the program to calculate that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your average is computed in integer arithmetic which means any fractional part is discarded. Consider using a floating point type for the average, and prefix the right hand side of the assignment with `1.0 *` to force the calculation to occur in floating point.
2. You must **not** reinitialise the random generator in the loop, else you ruin its statistical properties. Do it once before you enter the loop.

Comment: Both of these are excellent observations. Both address problems in the OP's code. Neither answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `while` loop, add

```
int prevTriesSum = 0;
```

Replace your commented `int average =` line with

```
prevTriesSum += tries;
```

And after the `for` loop add

```
double average = (prevTriesSum + 0.0) / counter;
outFile.println("It tool an average of " + average + " tries to win.");
```

As for the random number generator, Bathsheba is correct. You must move that above the `for` loop. Just move the declaration.

You'll also need to change your `for` loop slightly. As it stands, it will equal 1001 when the `for` loop terminates. Change it as follows:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < iNum; counter++)
```

This will ensure that your `average` calculation is correct.

Comment: Thanks so much. For the random number generator, do I just move "Random rand = new Random();" or do I also move "int iRand = rand.nextInt(5)+1;"? And, for the runs variable, why can't I use my counter variable I created in the for loop?

Comment: Just move the random number generator declaration, `Random rand = new Random();`. For the `runs` variable, I guess I wasn't paying enough attention. Your `counter` variable should be fine. Except you'll need to change the bounds of it to make it 0 based or you'll be off by one after the `for` loop terminates. I'll change it in the answer.